# How to remove overbraces from vertical equation alignment

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment, underbrace, overbrace

I am trying to use an overbrace, like this one:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{cases}
        \dot{\hat{x}}(t)\,=\,\overbrace{f(\hat{x}(t),u(t))}^{\text{text}}+K(t)\left(y(t)-\hat{y}(t)\right)\\
        \hat{y}(t)\,=\,h(\hat{x}(t),u(t))
    \end{cases}
\end{equation*} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

But I would like the vertical left braket not to consider the overbrace to compute its overall heigth. (I would like to remove the part highlighted in red)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to (a) "`\smash[t]`" the `\overbrace{...}^{...}` expression in the first row *and* (b) add a `\vphantom` immediately *after* the `cases` term. The argument of `\vphantom` should be a (suitably simplified, if possible) version of the same `cases` environment but *without* the `\smash` "wrapper" introduced in step (a).

The second step guards against the possibility that the material in the second argument of `\overbrace` might clash with any material in the paragraph immediately before the `equation*` material. This possibility is also mentioned in @barbarabeeton's comment on an [earlier answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/652325/5001).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
Initial form: Hello World. Hello World. Hello World. 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
  \dot{\hat{x}}(t) = \overbrace{f(\hat{x}(t),u(t))}^{\text{text}} +K(t)(y(t)-\hat{y}(t)) \\
  \hat{y}(t) = h(\hat{x}(t),u(t))
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

\medskip
Not good: \verb+\smash[t]+ alone. Hello World. Hello World. 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
  \dot{\hat{x}}(t) = \smash[t]{\overbrace{f(\hat{x}(t),u(t))}^{\text{text}}} +K(t)(y(t)-\hat{y}(t)) \\
  \hat{y}(t) = h(\hat{x}(t),u(t))
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

\medskip
Good: \verb+\smash[t]+ \emph{and} outer \verb+\vphantom+. Hello World. 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
  \dot{\hat{x}}(t) = \smash[t]{\overbrace{f(\hat{x}(t),u(t))}^{\text{text}}} +K(t)(y(t)-\hat{y}(t)) \\
  \hat{y}(t) = h(\hat{x}(t),u(t))
\end{cases}
\vphantom{% argument of \vphantom: the orig. 'cases' env., suitably simplified
  \begin{cases}
    \overbrace{f(\hat{x}(t))}^{\text{text}} \\
    .
  \end{cases}}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `\smash` command with the overbraced portion, which makes it be treated as if it had no height/width:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{cases}
        \dot{\hat{x}}(t)\,=\,\smash{\overbrace{f(\hat{x}(t),u(t))}^{\text{text}}}+K(t)\left(y(t)-\hat{y}(t)\right)\\
        \hat{y}(t)\,=\,h(\hat{x}(t),u(t))
    \end{cases}
\end{equation*} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This certainly fixes the height of the brace on the left.  But the overbrace and its explication might extend far enough to overprint text that is above it in a preceding paragraph..

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll have so many of such displays. Here's a way to proceed with minimal code duplication.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\obrace}[2]{{% one more brace
  \overbrace{#1}^{#2}%
}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[34][1-4]
\begin{equation*}
% define a local command
\newcommand{\thisequationwithobrace}{
  \begin{cases}
    \dot{\hat{x}}(t)=\perhapsobrace{f(\hat{x}(t),u(t))}{\mathrm{text}}+K(t)(y(t)-\hat{y}(t)) \\
    \hat{y}(t)=h(\hat{x}(t),u(t))
  \end{cases}
}
\newcommand{\perhapsobrace}[2]{\smash[t]{\obrace{#1}{#2}}}
\vphantom{\let\perhapsobrace\obrace\thisequationwithobrace}
\thisequationwithobrace
\end{equation*} 
\lipsum[35][1-4]

\end{document}
```

The idea is to store the code in a temporary macro that can be used to make a vertical phantom with `\obrace` having its standard meaning, but using `\perhapsobrace` in the body, allows to redefine it so it smashes the `\obrace`.

Wait! What's `\obrace`? There are two reasons for using such command instead of `\overbrace`. One reason is that it has standard arguments, so it's easy to define commands in terms of it; second and not less important reason, it will choose the right spacing around it.

If you're fussy about `\,=\,` (but you shouldn't), you should also be with the + after the overbraced material that isn't spaced correctly. You're also lucky enough that `\left` and `\right` don't choose oversized delimiters.

[image]